# How to download sql file from Azure Dev Ops repo in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, azure-devops, repository

Would like to download sql body files from Azure Dev Ops repository (just have sql code from sql file and store is as string or stream) in C# code. I am trying via below code:

```c
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri($"https://dev.azure.com/CodeRepo/");  //url of your organization
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", credentials);
      
                HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("PROJECT/_apis/git/repositories/Indexes/items?recursionLevel=Full&includeContentMetadata=true&api-version=6.0").Result;

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {

                    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RepoObject>(result);
                    
                    var jsonFilter = json.value.Where(a => a.isFolder == false && a.path.Substring(a.path.Length - 4, 4) == ".sql");

                    var dictOfFile = new Dictionary<string, int>();

                    var clientForSql = new HttpClient();

                   
                    foreach (var item in jsonFilter)
                    {
                        var buildUrl = $"PROJECT/_apis/git/repositories/Indexes/items?path={item.path}&api-version=6.0";
                        using (HttpResponseMessage responseFrom = client.GetAsync(
                              buildUrl).Result)
                        {
                            responseFrom.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                            string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                            Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
                            Console.ReadLine();
                        }

                    }    
                }
```

but it does not work.

responseBody which I get is a list of objects:

```
{
    "count": 3,
    "value": [{
            "objectId": "dd9a84209df2a5af0f6dd1108804711eb550baaa",
            "gitObjectType": "tree",
            "commitId": "da1d095a7cc8193563c9390dc9027aa4b63888",
            "path": "/",
            "isFolder": true,
            "contentMetadata": {
                "fileName": ""
            },
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/CodeRepo/5ce5f4b1-166f-4a19-9fff-123123123/_apis/git/repositories/5d2be668-af3a-4e2f-8cb9-f2dff888/items?path=%2F&versionType=Branch&versionOptions=None"
        }, 
            "objectId": "abafdb7cbbbc110a63eae18534c4c8eba888bbb",
            "gitObjectType": "tree",
            "commitId": "da1d095a7cc8193563c9390dc9027aa4b6888bbb",
            "path": "/Folder1/server1/database",
            "isFolder": true,
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/CodeRepo/Project/_apis/git/repositories/5d2be668-af3a-4e2f-8cb9-f2dffb888/items//Folder1/server1/database?versionType=Branch&versionOptions=None"
        }, {
            "objectId": "220145d24581c60c61bbd81355e5a5e4d9888bbb",
            "gitObjectType": "blob",
            "commitId": "da1d095a7cc8193563c9390dc9027aa4b6888bbb",
            "path": "/Folder1/server1/databases/IDX_1.sql",
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/CodeRepo/Project/_apis/git/repositories/5d2be668-af3a-4e2f-8cb9-f2dffb888items//Folder1/server1/database/IDX_1.sql?versionType=Branch&versionOptions=None"
        }, {
            "objectId": "ef8feb5b92e32c46f74400ae8fda000f15888bbb",
            "gitObjectType": "blob",
            "commitId": "da1d095a7cc8193563c9390dc9027aa4b6888bbb",
            "path": "/NamingConvention.md",
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/CodeRepo/Project/_apis/git/repositories/5d2be668-af3a-4e2f-8cb9-f2dffb888/items//NamingConvention.md?versionType=Branch&versionOptions=None"
        }
    ]
}
```

Even If change part of code:

```
foreach (var item in jsonFilter)
                    {
                        //var buildUrl = $"Project/_apis/git/repositories/Indexes/items?path={item.path}&api-version=6.0";


                        using (HttpResponseMessage responseFrom = client.GetAsync(
                              item.url).Result)
                        {
                            responseFrom.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                            string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                            Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
                            Console.ReadLine();
                        }

                    }
```

I still getting same response as above. If copy the url address and paste it to browser I see body of sql file.

Do you have idea how to get sql file as stream or string ?

Comment: Yes but when I am trying to send request via `client.GetAsync` to this url I am getting result which I show above (all objects). When I am copy and paste this url in browser I see body of sql file.

Comment: What dou you mean by C ? I check was trying to send request with url from IDS_1.sql but in response I get same list of files as I show in post. When I am coping this url (from IDS_1.sql) to browser it is showing me body file (this what I want to achieve in code).